# Different resource files, jars for debug and release builds

Tags: android

I am creating an android project which uses a bunch of resource (xml) files and a jar. I want to have different xml files for debug and release builds and if possible, different jars too.
Is there a way to do this?
So, if I do create a debug build, it should by default pick up the debug xml files and the debug jar and in case of a release build, it should pick up the release xml file and the release jar.
One way I can think of for xml files is to import both the xml files and use BuildConfig.DEBUG to distinguish between different types of builds and make the distinction at run time. But I can't think of doing this for jar files.

Comment: you can customize build.xml for the purpose and add custom rules that will modify resources in project depending on build type.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Ant plugin to automate builds with custom rules.
Please follow this [Link](http://www.androidengineer.com/2010/06/using-ant-to-automate-building-android.html)

This will help you in solving following queries

```
Add custom build steps.

Use an automated build system.

Use build configurations.

Build the release project with one command.
```